# Java FTP commons-net error downloading files

Tags: java, ftp

I'm using apache commons.net to access an ftp site which is the directory is in unix:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
```

I'm looping thru a list with the names of the filenames I want to download on a specific ftp site

```
String ftpPath = "/home/user1/input/";
FileOutputStream fos = null;
File file;

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        file = new File(ftpPath+fileList.get(i).toString());
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        boolean download = ftpClient.retrieveFile("c:/test/downloadedFile.csv", outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();
        if (download) {
           System.out.println("File downloaded successfully !");
        } else {
           System.out.println("Error in downloading file ! " + downloadFile);
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But once I try to start to download the files I get this error althougth checking the ftp site the file exists under /home/user1/input/TejasSDH_PM_AU_09_07_2014_09_00.csv -rw-r--r--:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \home\user1\input\TejasSDH_PM_AU_09_07_2014_09_00.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
at com.syntronic.client.FTPDataExtract$1.downloadTejasFiles(FTPDataExtract.java:255)
at com.syntronic.client.FTPDataExtract$1.run(FTPDataExtract.java:133)
```

I'm thinking as the ftp site I'm connecting, the path dir is in unix home/user1/input and java is converting all the "/" to "\". Anyone has an idea on what the error in eclipse means or is something wrong with my code? thank you

Comment: nablex, thank you I finally get what your trying to say. So stupid of me. I switched the remote from the local path. Need to see a doctor soon doing codes for 8hrs straight is making my mind slow.  again thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be switching things around.

You are opening a file outputstream to `\home\user1\input\TejasSDH_PM_AU_09_07_2014_09_00.csv` and you seem to be on windows so it won't work.

You have the local path where the ftp path should go and the other way around.

Please read your errors more carefully, I'm willing to bet that line 255 in FTPDataExtract.java is:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);
```

Which should alert you to the fact that it's not actually an ftp problem.

Comment: I see what you mean. I updated the code (seen above) as I'm currently finding a solution for this but the same error still shows even changing the output stream to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
    OutputStream output;
    output = new FileOutputStream("C:/test/" + fileList.get(i).toString());
    ftpClient.retrieveFile(ftpPath + fileList.get(i).toString(), output); 
    output.close();
}
```

I wrongfully switch the remote and local path, switching it properly will run the program smoothly.